# swap two structures in c++ using a user function

Tags: c++, structure, swap

i have the following code that looks just fine for me 
my intention is to swap the two structures name's and cne's 
but the "echange" function doesn't look like doing anything 
this the code that i wrote :

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct etudiant{
    char* nom ;
    int cne ;
};
void echanger(etudiant khalil,etudiant ait){
    etudiant *pt;
    pt = &khalil ;
    char* n ;
    int p ;
    n = ait.nom ;
    p = ait.cne ;
    ait.cne = pt->cne ;
    ait.nom = pt->nom ;
    khalil.cne = p;
    khalil.nom = n;
}
int main(){
    etudiant khalil ;
    etudiant ait ;
    khalil.cne = 123 ; khalil.nom = "khalil" ;
    ait.cne = 789 ; ait.nom = "ait" ;
    cout << "khalil : nom =>  " << khalil.nom << " ; cne => " << khalil.cne << endl;
    cout << "ait    : nom =>  " << ait.nom << " ; cne => " << ait.cne << endl;
    echanger(khalil,ait);
    cout << "khalil => nom : " << khalil.nom <<" ,cne : " << khalil.cne << endl;
    cout << "ait =>  nom : " << ait.nom <<" ,cne : " << ait.cne << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The function parameters are passed by value so are copies of your variables defined in main.  Make them references.

Comment: You're passing the arguments by value. That means that function gets copies of the actual arguments in each call. It can do whatever it wants with those copies (though not with what they reference via pointers), without affecting anything.

Comment: This is very basic C++, and something [reading any good beginners book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/440558) should have taught you.

Comment: Also remember that structures can be copied *whole*, which means your function body could be just three lines long.

Comment: i totally forgot about the reference

Comment: void echanger(etudiant &khalil,etudiant &ait){
        etudiant tmp ;
        tmp = khalil;
        khalil = ait ;
        ait = tmp ;
    }

Comment: @khalilkasmi -- *i have the following code that looks just fine for me* -- It would look fine if you used Java.  The problem is that C++ is not Java.  In C++, passing objects by value creates a temporary copy.

Comment: Always a good idea to use a debugger, especially when you are learning. If you stepped through this code line-by-line while watching the variables you would see what is happening for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use

```
void echanger(etudiant khalil,etudiant ait){
```

you are passing a copy of the objects to `echanger`. Any changes made to `khalil` and `ait` in the function are not visible to the calling function. They are changes to the local copy. To make the changes visible in the calling function, the function needs to use reference types in the arguments.

```
void echanger(etudiant& khalil, etudiant& ait){
//                    ^                 ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters are pass-by-value so you are only changing copies of the originals in main.

Change your function to take the parameters as references (or pointers) instead.

Also consider using [std::swap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/) instead of implementing your own.

Comment: i 'am a c++ beginner , using the std::swap function wouldn't help much

Comment: @khalilkasmi What do you mean it wouldn't help much? `std::swap` is a function of the standard library in the same capacity that `cout` is a member of the standard library. That's what it's there for, for you to learn and utilize. You being a beginner is exactly why he mentioned it, meaning you probably didn't realize that it existed.

Comment: @Chris I think they mean that they are trying to implement their own swap function to help them learn. Nothing wrong with that, it’s a good way to learn. But yes, I agree, in the real world we would use std::swap

Comment: @GrahamS fair enough. Fortunately the issue wasn't necessarily the actual swapping, as was the passing-by-reference. Definitely helpful to know both methods.

Comment: @chris IT WAS helpful to know both methodes and i appreciate that